# How to "rewrite" urls or routes with Play Framework 2

Tags: scala, url-rewriting, routes, playframework-2.0

I've a Play Framework 2 Website, and it works perfectly, but the way that play work with urls doesn't satisfy me.
Let me explain : for example, I've a route for user log out, so I've a redirection to my index page, but in the url I still have "localhost:9000/**logout**", and for me it's not very explicit, I will prefer a simple "localhost:9000/" or "localhost:9000/index" ; I've some cases like that and I want to know if it's possible to change that, like url rewriting.

I haven't found any helpful topics on the internet, so I hope that you may have a solution for me !

Comment: Do a Redirect (btw rewrite has other meaning)

Comment: That's what I wanted, thanks @applicius ! (I misspoke, sorry).

Comment: @Govind Singh Nagarkoti, I wnated to call logOut method, but without url change. Redirect() do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you right your logout action returns the index view instead of a redirect.

In your controller action corresponding to **/logout** mapping you need to redirect a user to the home page.

Here is an example controller:

```
object HomeController extends Controller {

  def index() = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.index())
  }

  def logout() = Action { implicit request =>
    //logout a user
    Redirect(routes.HomeController.index())
  }
}
```

Route definition:

```
GET         /            controllers.HomeController.index
GET         /logout      controllers.HomeController.logout
```

Comment: That's the answer ! :)